# Is it possible to reference a values column in a calculated field

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I've created a pivot table in excel that has two value fields. Both are SUMs of their target columns. I want to create a calculated field that divides the first value field by the second.

Is that possible?

```
Site  | Count | Pop | Ratio 
------------------------
TX    | 12    | 15  | .8
- AAA | 3     | 4   | .75
- BBB | 5     | 10  | .5
- CCC | 4     | 1   | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the results as any other data. Something along the lines of:

```
=( B2 / C2 )
```

Where B2 and C2 are cells with the results (sums).